# How to add dynamic 'where' to eloquent ORM with() relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm, trying to do something like this:

```
$verfuegbarkeiten = Verfuegbarkeit::verfuegbar()->with('product', 'producer', 'producer.user', 'producer.user.ort')->where('product.kategorie_id', '=', $_GET['kat'])->get()->toArray();
```

I want to use a 'where' clause so i can only get the results where the 'product's attribute 'kategorie_id' matches the GET parameter. How can I 'where' on a relation? It's really important to me that this value can be dynamic, so writing a fix function in the related Model won't be a good solution.

Every hint appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `whereHas()`, documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

For your example, that would mean something like this:

```
$kat = $_GET['kat'];
$verfuegbarkeiten = Verfuegbarkeit::verfuegbar()
    ->with('product', 'producer', 'producer.user', 'producer.user.ort')
    ->whereHas('product', function($query) use ($kat) {
        $query->where('kat', $kat);
    })
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Although I might add that using `$_GET` is generally discouraged in Laravel.

Comment: Unfortunattely this won't work, because `whereHas` constraint works only for specific relation collection - not for main table - so it won't filter out data.

Comment: I'm sorry @FilipKoblański, I don't understand quite what you mean. This will get all Verfuegbarkeit objects that have a product matching ?kat=, which seems to be exactly what he wants.